# how can i save a foreign key with null value by spring boot jpa?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, save

In my application i need to save foreign key as a null . but background jpa create a primary key in primary table then it save this id  in foreign key table . but i need to save null value for my application criteria.
my foreign key table here..

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"courses","handler","hibernateLazyInitializer"})
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional=true)
@JoinColumn(columnDefinition="Long default null",name = "ref_id")
private Reference ref;

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"courses","authorName","edition"})
@ManyToOne(cascade =  {CascadeType.DETACH})
@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
private Book books;


@JsonIgnoreProperties({"books","handler","hibernateLazyInitializer"})
@ManyToOne(cascade =  {CascadeType.DETACH})
@JoinColumn(name = "ch_id")
private Chapter chapters;
```

primary key table

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "ref", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<QuestionerDefination> questionerDefinations;
```

my bussiness criteria is " when i save book id then refId should be null and when i save ref_id then book id should be null"

i try to insert data jpa native query but when i try to save null value then  postgres makes a exception "integer but expression is of type bytea" so i am failed to save data .

how can i save foreign key with a null value ? can u tell me plz?
thank you.